# Apex heap size too large Exception in - Batch

Tags: batch

We have 2 objects : **Order_Integration__c**, **Order**.
We are running the batch **Copying order integration table data** to **order table**.

Requirement : If any error occurs while creating order. ***That respective Error Information, need to capture under respective "Order Integration Table".*** Order Integration and order Linked through External Id.

For Doing that : I had written below Logic :

Code Snippet:

```
for (Database.upsertResult res : lsr) {  //Lsr is  inserted orderList
                for(order ord:upsertOrderList){ //Lsr is complete 
orderIntegrtaion TableList
                   if (res.isSuccess()) {
                        
                    }
                    else{
                       
                        for(Database.Error err : res.getErrors()){
                        
                           error+= err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage();
                            error+= 'Fields: '+err.getFields();
                            error+='\n';
                             Order_Integration__c ordInt = new Order_Integration__c();
                            ordInt.Id=ord.Order_Integration_Ids__c;
                            ordInt.Status_Description__c = error;
                            ordIntegrationList.add(ordInt);
                }
                }
                }
                }
```

***Exception Received:***

```
              System.LimitException: Apex heap size too large: 17542735.
```

Seems Like Its because of for with for Loop Iteration. If I avoid ,for within for how can I achieve this requirement.

Completed Code:

```
for(Order_Integration__c ord:scope){
     order ord = new order();
     ord.Order_Integration_Ids__c = orderIntegrate.Id;
         --- so on -----
     upsertOrderList.add(ord);
  }

 //Upsert orderList -> creating OrderRecord List

   if (upsertOrderList.size() > 0) {
            Database.upsertResult[] lsr = 
  Database.upsert(upsertOrderList,order.fields.External_Id__c,false);
            Integer recordid = 0;
            error = '';
            integer count = 0;
            for (Database.upsertResult res : lsr) {
                for(order ord:upsertOrderList){
                    if (res.isSuccess()) {
                        if(res.isCreated()){
                            successRecCount++;  
                        }
                        orderIdSet.add(res.getId());
                    }
                    else{
                        hasErrors = true;
                        for(Database.Error err : res.getErrors()){
                             errorRecCount++;
                            Order_Integration__c ordInt = new Order_Integration__c();
                            ordInt.Id=ord.Order_Integration_Ids__c;
                            error+= err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage();
                            error+= 'Fields: '+err.getFields();
                            error+='\n';
                            ordInt.Status_Description__c = error;
                            ordIntegrationList.add(ordInt);
                            if(err.getStatusCode() == system.StatusCode.REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING){
                                if(errorMap.containsKey(err.getMessage())){
                                    count = errorMap.get(err.getMessage());
                                    errorMap.put(err.getMessage(),++count);
                                }else{
                                    errorMap.put(err.getMessage(),1);
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        
        
        if(!ordIntegrationList.isempty()){
            map<id,Order_Integration__c> errorDescriptionMap = new map<id,Order_Integration__c>();
            //put all the values from the list to map. 
            errorDescriptionMap.putall(ordIntegrationList);
            if(errorDescriptionMap.size()>0){
                update errorDescriptionMap.values();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you `error = ''` be inside `for(order ord:upsertOrderList){` as you are creating `Order_Integration__c` object while iterating upsertOrderList. Basically the issue is you String `error` is going beyond 12MB limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First your core logic of checking if a record is success or not is incorrect. . As it will always create junk `Order_Integration__c` records for each `upsertOrderList`.

As per your code lets say if first result in `lsr` is not successful, so the code will go ahead iterate on all `upsertOrderList` and create `Order_Integration__c` records for all `upsertOrderList` in else condition.

For checking if a upsert has passed successfully or not check [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189138/database-upsert-how-to-find-which-records-have-inserted-updated-based-on-exter)

As explained here order of the result and the upsert records will be always same.

```
for (Integer index = 0; index < lsr.size(); index++) {
    error = '';
    errorRecCount = 0;
    if(lsr[index].isSuccess() && lsr[index].isCreated()){
        if (lsr[index].isCreated()) {
            successRecCount++;
        }
        orderIdSet.add(lsr[index].getId());
    } else {
        hasErrors = true;
        for (Database.Error err : lsr[index].getErrors()) {
            errorRecCount++;
            Order_Integration__c ordInt = new Order_Integration__c();
            ordInt.Id = upsertOrderList[index].Order_Integration_Ids__c;
            error += err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage();
            error += 'Fields: ' + err.getFields();
            error += '\n';
            ordInt.Status_Description__c = error;
            ordIntegrationList.add(ordInt);
            if (err.getStatusCode() == system.StatusCode.REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING) {
                if (errorMap.containsKey(err.getMessage())) {
                    count = errorMap.get(err.getMessage());
                    errorMap.put(err.getMessage(), ++count);
                } else {
                    errorMap.put(err.getMessage(), 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the exception , I believe you are initializing `error = ''` and `errorRecCount` in wrong place. It should be inside the for loop like shown above.

The issue is as you have initialized `String` at top and concatenating it always, so there might be scenario in your batch where that `String` is growing beyond 12MB of heap limit.

Comment: error issue resolved by mistake added that complete error code. how to resolve  that mapping order and order integration failed record issue?

Comment: concantenate string causing that issue..understood. how to resolve maping issue

Comment: Its explained beautifully by @sfdcfox in the link i have given above, but also sharing an example in above snippet.

Comment: Thanks Nagendra